Does the fundamental group of a compact 3-manifold induce full profinite topology on the fundamental group of its boundary?
Let $M^3$ be a compact, orientable, irreducible 3-manifold with incompressible boundary. Let $S\subseteq\partial M$ be one of its boundary components. Does $\pi_1(M)$ induce the full profinite topology on the subgroup $\pi_1(S)$? Namely, for any finite index subgroup $H\le \pi_1(S)$, does there exist a finite index subgroup $K\le \pi_1(M)$ such that $K\cap \pi_1(S)\subseteq H$?
This is equivalent to say that for any finite cover $\widetilde{S}$ of $S$, does there exist a finite cover $p: \widetilde{M}^\ast \to M$ such that a component $p^{-1}(S)\to S$ factors through $\widetilde{S}$?
Note that Long-Niblo showed that $\pi_1(S)$ is separable in $\pi_1(M)$, i.e. closed in the profinite topology. So my question is also equivalent to whether every finite index subgroup of $\pi_1(S)$ is also separable in $\pi_1(M)$.
The result holds when the boundary of $M$ is a collection of tori, based on the JSJ-decomposition and the finite covers constructed by Hamilton.

All these manifold groups are virtually special, hence, LERF.

@MoisheKohan: this isn't quite right. Liu discovered that many 3-manifold groups, including many virtually special ones, are not LERF: https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.4674 .

It should be possible to answer this question using Hongbin Sun's characterisation of separable subgroups of 3-manifold groups: https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.08580 .

@HJRW: Yes, I misremembered.

@HJRW: Sun and Liu's result is sufficient for an affirmative answer to my question,  thanks.

Great! It could be nice to summarise how to apply their results in an answer to this question.

@HJRW: In a recent paper by Xu (Proposition 6.1), this result was reproved based on the result of Sun and Liu mentioned above.

This is also proved by Wilkes in Corollary 6.20.
